# Pandas prod() function false result

Tags: pandas

I created a pandas series of numbers from 1 to 20. When I tried .prod() function on series it returns false result. Why it returns a negative number although there is no negative number in series???

```
import pandas as pd
dh=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])
dh.prod()
result= -4249290049419214848
```

Comment: I was able to replicate your error and it's weird it shouldn't output a negative number. I ran an iteration i saw that after the `Series > 20 ` it starts spitting out negative wrong results. I hope you get a helpful answer here, also I realized that doesn't happen if you use floats.

Comment: If you run it in numpy, you get the same negative error,``np.prod([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])``, which makes me believe it stems from somewhere within numpy.The [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46573) here might be related. Note that `math.prod` does not have this issue. I think for now, your best bet is to convert to floats before computing prod. Alternatively, if you are up for it, you could do some more investigation and submit a PR to fix it